# Evaluating Macro Arguments in Expansion

Tags: elisp-macros

In Section 13.5.4 of the [Elisp reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Eval-During-Expansion.html#Eval-During-Expansion), we are shown a problem whereby a macro definition evaluates one of its argument expressions.

```
(defmacro foo (a)
  (list 'setq (eval a) t))
(setq x 'b)
(foo x) → (setq b t)
     ⇒ t                  ; and b has been set.
;; but
(setq a 'c)
(foo a) → (setq a t)
     ⇒ t                  ; but this set a, not c.
```

We are then advised to

> substitute the expression into the macro expansion, so that its value will be computed as part of executing the expansion.

I'm not sure what this means, but I interpret it as meaning that we should try to rewrite the macro as follows:

```
(defmacro foo (a)
  `(setq (eval ',a) t))
```

Which, when expanded, gives:

```
(macroexpand '(foo x)) → (setq (eval (quote x)) t)
```

But I'm getting the following error when I call `(foo x)`:

```
(wrong-type-argument symbolp (eval (quote x)))
```

Even though when I evaluate `(symbolp (eval (quote x)))`, the result is `t`.

It seems that there's something fundamental that I'm not understanding here. What's the issue?

Comment: It's a typo in the manual, it should read: "but this set c, not a." You might want to write about it to Emacs ailing list.

Comment: @wvxvw: No, I don't think so. It sets `a`, not `c`. (But there is a typo: "set" should be "sets".)

Comment: @Drew Oh, I see now, I've missed the whole point of this article :) Yeah, it's not a typo. I just wasn't careful to read it through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `setq` does not evaluate its first argument, so your second defmacro definition cannot work.  The error message tells you that `setq` expects a symbol as its first argument, but you passed it the list `(eval (quote x))` instead.
2. The problem with the original code is that there is variable capture: the parameter of the defmacro is `a`, as is the variable passed to `foo`.

Comment: Ah, of course, this looks like a job for `set` instead! And the modified macro with `set` does seem to work properly, including for "a" where `(setq   a 'c)`. Two questions: how are we avoiding variable capture, and don't we still have the issue of expansion during byte-compilation? How *should* a macro that does what we want be written?

Comment: To avoid variable capture, the code produced by macroexpansion (and then evaluated) needs to bind new variables. See the Elisp manual, node [Surprising Local Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Surprising-Local-Vars.html). (See also the other nodes about defining Lisp macros.)

Comment: What "issue of expansion during byte-compilation"?

Comment: From the same node: Another problem with calling ‘eval’ in a macro definition is that it probably won’t do what you intend in a compiled program.  The byte compiler runs macro definitions while compiling the program, when the program’s own computations (which you might have wished to access with ‘eval’) don’t occur and its local variable bindings don’t exist.

Comment: The way I understand it, if we have `(eval a)` in the macro as in the original example, the byte-compiler tries to expand the macro when the file is compiled, but `a` is not yet defined. I'm assuming the backquote-comma construct has the same problem, since "comma" is basically a marker shorthand for `eval`?

Comment: At byte-compile time a macro body is evaluated, and the resulting code (the expansion is substituted for the macro call and then byte-compiled. In your case, if you put `(foo a)` in your code it's just as if you had written `(setq (eval a) t)` in the code - that is the sexp that ultimately gets byte-compiled. Which leads to the same problem, yes.